# How do I find an object by type and name, in Unity, using C#?

Tags: unity, c#

I know that in Unity you can find an object of a certain type, using `myObject = Object.FindObjectsOfType<MyType>()`, but that only returns the first object in the scene it finds of that type.

How do I make it find the object of a certain type **and** with a certain name?

Comment: No, the method you've shown, `FindObjectsOfType` (with Object**s** pluralised) returns an array of all such objects found. You can then iterate over the array to find one with a matching name. [But please don't. ;)](https://twitter.com/D_M_Gregory/status/672973048899702784)

Comment: I didn't really get why not (and by the way it's not a GameObject that i'm looking for). Is there any other way than iterating through the array or that's it?

Comment: It's a working solution - I'm being a bit hyperbolic. But string-based lookups are generally more error-prone than other strategies, and can lead to unintuitive errors & exotic workarounds like the one in that tweet (this code depended on another script that looked up objects by name, which would select the old destroyed copy before it was deleted instead of the newly-spawned copy, leading to missing reference errors on the next frame). In my experience in Unity there's always more reliable & robust methods available. If you describe your use case in more detail we may be able to suggest some.

Comment: I'll try the array iteration first since it's a very small scene with only 2 objects of the same type that i have to tell the difference between. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways you would go about this depending on your particular circumstances.

Ultimately, you can not search for all active game objects based off both *type* and *name*, at the same time. You can easily search for all active game objects based off *type*, and search the resulting list for all game objects of *type* that use *name*. You also want to consider whether searching for game objects by *tag* would be more appropriate for your requirements.

Below, I have provided two methods for searching for game objects by *type* and *name*. One can be easily used on the fly, the other is provided as a standalone method, and can be used more dynamically.

---

#### Find all GameObject(s) by *type* and *name*

To complete the search, simply search for objects based off *type*, and search through the resulting list for objects that match the *name*.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

...

    TypeToLookFor[] firstList = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<TypeToLookFor>();
    List<Object> finalList = new List<Object>();
    string nameToLookFor = "name of game object";

    for(var i = 0; i < firstList.Length; i++)
    {
        if(firstList[i].gameObject.name == nameToLookFor)
        {
            finalList.Add(firstList[i]);
        }
    }
```

Note that you ask to "find objects", and I interpret that to literally mean you wish to have a resulting `Object` array. Any type you can look for, in this way, will be compatible with `Object`.

You could also retain the type you originally search for, in this way. In the above example, we could change `List<Object> finalList` to `List<TypeToLookFor>` with no problems. We could also use `List<GameObject> finalList`, and find the actual `gameObject` reference with `finalList.Add(basicAIList[i].gameObject`, if we wanted a list of game objects.

---

Consider that you may want to search like this multiple times. It might be more useful to have a standalone method that can perform the required search, and take in custom types and names.

```
...

public List<Object> FindObjectsOfTypeAndName<T>(string name) where T : MonoBehaviour
{
    MonoBehaviour[] firstList = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<T>();
    List<Object> finalList = new List<Object>();

    for(var i = 0; i < firstList.Length; i++)
    {
        if(firstList[i].name == name)
        {
            finalList.Add(firstList[i]);
        }
    }

    return finalList;
}
```

We can then call this method as `FindObjectsOfTypeAndName<TypeToLookFor>("name to look for")`.

I assume that we will always be looking for types that inherit from `MonoBehaviour`, but this will usually be the case, with custom types. If you need to change this, ensure that you also change the type of `MonoBehaviour[] firstList`.

Comment: I like a lot the second solution from Gnemlock, but when trying it, I found a problem: I wrote Canvas as Type(T) and I got error cs0311: The type 'UnityEngine.Canvas' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Counters.FindObjectsOfTypeAndName<T>(string)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'UnityEngine.Canvas' to 'UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour'. Is this normal? Am I doing anything wrong? Thank yoU!

Comment: @Kaprojo it sounds like you want to relax the type constraint on `FindObjectsOfTypeAndName` from `where T : MonoBehaviour` to `where T : Component`. Every `MonoBehaviour` is a `Component`, but not all of the built-in components you might want to search for is a `MonoBehaviour`.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the name and type of object (as in they definitely exist), then it's a simple line of code.

For example, let's say you have a Canvas and it's called MyCanvas.

```
Canvas myCanvas = GameObject.Find("MyCanvas").GetComponent<Canvas>();
```

Or more generally:

*Type* *varName* = GameObject.Find("*ComponentName*").GetComponent<*Type*>();

This assumes that you do only have one object of that name, but provides a nice clean piece of code that does what is required for many use cases.

Answer (score -4):

You can use GameObject.FindObjectsWithTag("tag") function instead

Comment: This solution finds objects of *tag*, but ignores both *type* and *name*.